# Res is coming back as a null value, not sure why (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

whenever I run my program, an exeption occurs where res comes back as null. The program successful uploads to firebase, and the input value isn't empty, so I'm not sure why the value doesn't come back as anything.

Here is the code involved.

The line occus on this line of the _onPublish Function, "builder: (context) => NewsPostPage(newsPostId: res!)));", and it reads, "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)"

When a button is pressed, it calls function _onPublish

```
_onPublish() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });

      await DatabaseService()
          .saveNewsPost(
              _titleEditingController.text, _contentEditingController.text)
          .then((res) async {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NewsPostPage(newsPostId: res!)));
        _isLoading = true;
        print("Post Uploaded to Firebase");
      });
    }
  }
```

Here is function Database Service.saveNewsPost()

```
Future saveNewsPost(
    String title,
    String content,
  ) async {
    DocumentReference newsPostsRef =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('newsPosts').add({
      'newsPostId': '',
      'newsPostTitle': title,
      'newsPostTitleArray': title.toLowerCase().split(" "),
      //'newsPostAuthor': author,
      'newsPostContent': content,
      'createdAt': new DateTime.now(),
      'date': DateFormat.yMMMd('en_US').format(DateTime.now())
    });

    await newsPostsRef.update({'newsPostId': newsPostsRef.id});
//return
    newsPostsRef.id;
  }
```

Lastly, here is NewsPostPage

```
class NewsPostPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String newsPostId;
  //final String authorName;
  NewsPostPage({
    required this.newsPostId,
    /*required this.authorName*/
  });

  @override
  _NewsPostPageState createState() => _NewsPostPageState();
}

class _NewsPostPageState extends State<NewsPostPage> {
  newsPostDetails NewsPostDetails = newsPostDetails();
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String _error = '';
  TextEditingController _fullNameEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  late DocumentReference newsPostRef;
  late DocumentSnapshot newsPostSnap;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNewsPostDetails;
  }

  _getNewsPostDetails() async {
    await DatabaseService().getNewsPostDetails(widget.newsPostId).then((res) {
      setState(() {
        NewsPostDetails = res;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });

    newsPostRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('blogPosts')
        .doc(widget.newsPostId);
    newsPostSnap = await newsPostRef.get();

    print(newsPostSnap.data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: Text(NewsPostDetails.newsPostTitle! as String),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: ListView(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 50.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(NewsPostDetails.newsPostTitle as String,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40.0,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('Published on - ${NewsPostDetails.date as String}',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.grey)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    Text(NewsPostDetails.newsPostContent as String,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0)),
                    SizedBox(height: 110.0),
                  ]),
            ));
  }
}
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not returning anything in `DatabaseService().saveNewsPost()`. You commented the `return` before `newsPostsRef.id`